# Flutter Checkbox - how to set colour in unchecked state

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In Flutter a Checkbox appears to be transparent, in its natural unchecked state. I would like to know how to set the colour of the box in this state.

There are many similar questions here but they all ask to change the active colour, or the colour of the tick. I've tried all of the available properties but none of them seem to affect the unchecked state (not even fillColor). My goal is to create a solid white checkbox (square with rounded corners) which shows up against a non-white background.

```dart
child: Checkbox(
  checkColor: Colors.red,
  activeColor: Colors.white,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
  onChanged: (value) {},
),
```

[image]

Comment: Can you include an image that you are trying to archive?

Comment: Image added as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paint has been done on source code. we can trick the UI by wrapping `Checkbox` with `Container` and providing `decoration` also we need to changes some properties on `Checkbox`.

```dart
child: Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
  ),
  child: Checkbox(
    value: _isChecked,
    hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
    fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white),
    checkColor: Colors.red,
    activeColor: Colors.white,
    shape:
        RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
    onChanged: (value) {
      setState(() {
        _isChecked = !_isChecked;
      });
    },
  ),
),
```

[image]
[image]

To improve padding-space, we can use `Transform.scale` and control the size from `Container`. but for too small(~12) cases, It may cause some UI trouble.

```dart
 Container(
  width: 24,
  height: 24,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
  ),
  child: Transform.scale(
    scale: 1.2,
    child: Checkbox(...
```

[image]

Comment: This looks great, however it's appearing too large - how can I control or reduce the size please? I have a lot more white padding than in your sample image...

Comment: Yea, I've also noticed that, it is coming from default padding I think, this can be translated using Transform scale and parent size will be controlled by Container.

Comment: One small point about this solution is that there is no touch feedback other than the tick appearing. Can this be added in some way?